# BASH reports file does not exist but it does

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script

I have a list of files produced from find. Due to some poor planning from management I need to now stat these files, but the find command took several hours to complete as we're scanning several TB of data. So my plan was to run through the list of files with a script, and run the stat based on the files we already found. The issue is that BASH is continually reporting that all of the files do not exist, within the script, but executing any command with the files out of the script (just on the terminal) works fine.

EX:

```
sh ~/temp.sh  | head -1
stat: ./2017\ Digital/redacted\ Projects-redacted-IP.idx: stat: No such file or directory

stat -x ./2017\ Digital/redacted\ Projects-redacted-IP.idx
  File: "./2017 Digital/redacted Projects-redacted-IP.idx"
  Size: 25165824     FileType: Regular File
  Mode: (0500/-r-x------)         Uid: (redacted)  Gid: (redacted)
Device: 47,12   Inode: 440520    Links: 1
Access: Wed Jul  5 17:24:48 2017
Modify: Wed Jul  5 17:24:48 2017
Change: Wed Jul  5 17:24:48 2017

i=0
IFS=$'\n'
for j in $(cat ~/files); do
    stat -x $j
done
```

These are Windows shares mounted to /Volumes/ in OSX. Regardless of how I seem to change the quotations (double/single/none/etc) the script continually reports that ALL of the files do not exist. I've also tried a python version of the script:

```
from subprocess import call
f=open( "/Users/me/files", "r" )
for l in f:
    call(["stat","-x","/Volumes/"+l])
```

With the same error. The issue seems to be directly related to spaces in the filenames. Since when hardcoding a different file, with no spaces, it works just fine. I'm assuming I need to do something with quoting my variables differently? But I can't, for the life of me, figure out what the proper way to quote those variables is to get it to work.

Comment: Does ~/files actually contain escapes (backslashes) before the spaces? If so, that'll cause this problem, since the backslashes will be treated as part of the file path. Also, `for j in $(cat ~/files)` is a bad way to iterate over the contents of a file, use a `while read` loop instead (see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [#20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)).

Comment: Not sure I understand. The contents of the file look like this:

./Transfer/some\ user/Transit\ 360s/WGN/tranwgn_18_whitegold/somefile.jpg

Eg they include the backslashes to escape the " " characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the paths listed in ~/files include escapes (backslashes) before spaces (and possibly other characters), and these are getting treated as part of the filename. Normally, when you enter a command like this:

```
stat -x ./2017\ Digital/redacted\ Projects-redacted-IP.idx
```

the shell's parsing process interprets the backslashes as meaning that the spaces are part of the argument (rather than separators between arguments), *and then it removes them* before passing the argument to `stat`. Thus, stat actually receives two arguments: `-x` and `./2017 Digital/redacted Projects-redacted-IP.idx`.

On the other hand, when you read the filepaths from a file, it never goes through that parse-and-remove escapes step, so the escapes are passed to `stat` as part of the argument, and it looks for files that actually have backslashes in their names (and doesn't find them).

Quoting will not help with this. The shell parses (and removes) escapes, quotes, and such *before* substituting variable values, so it never winds up interpreting & removing escapes and quotes from their values. (Well, unless you use something like `eval`, but don't do that -- it opens up way to many opportunities for new things to go wrong.)

It turns out there's an easy way to do the escape parsing & removal from the file's contents. In a comment, I recommended switching from a `for` loop to a `while read` loop and linked [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). If you read that, it actually recommends using `while IFS= read -r`, and says:

> The `-r` option to `read` prevents backslash interpretation (usually used
>   as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines or to
>   escape the delimiters). Without this option, any unescaped backslashes
>   in the input will be discarded. You should almost always use the `-r`
>   option with `read`.

...except in this case you *want* backslashes to be interpreted and removed ("discarded"), so just leave off the `-r`. Oh, and then wrap all variable references in double-quotes to prevent it being split on spaces (without double-quotes, splitting happens whether or not the spaces are escaped):

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while IFS= read j; do
    stat -x "$j"
done <~/files
```